# Can i know why Visual Studio 2017 archive is different from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, build, xamarin.android

The difference between vs 2017 and 2019 apk
[image: The difference between vs 2017 and 2019 apk]

Ive embedded all the projects and the result when i check with cmd command which is "strings (apk path)| grep pdb.

The result of cmd command is:

Visual studio 2019 apk (I highlighted the path(which shouldn't show))
[image: Visual studio 2019 apk (I highlighted the path(which shouldn't show))]
Visual studio 2017 apk(this is the path i want)
[image: Visual studio 2017 apk(this is the path i want)]

How do i make make visual studio 2019 to display pdb file without the directories?

Answer (score 0):

When you debug a project in the Visual Studio IDE, the debugger automatically loads symbol files that are located in the project folder.You could specify symbol locations and loading options: 
 In Visual Studio, open **Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols**

[image]

For more details about **Specify symbol (.pdb)** you could refer the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#symbol-file-locations-and-loading-behavior) .

Comment: Where and what to browse? And why visual studio 2017 does not need this browse directory? Is that a way i can set it to empty path so it only shows the pdb file?

Comment: You could report the question to : Help -> Send Feedback ->Report a problem  .